# Which java to use for successfully running minecraft?

Tags: java, minecraft

I can run minecraft perfectly fine on versions 1.12 and above, but as soon as I use older versions of the game, such as 1.8.9 I get prompted with "Unable to access address of buffer" whenever I try to join a multiplayer server. I beleive this is due to my version of java jdk because I have seen others with this problem who have switched from java 11 to java 8. I switched by using sudo -s, and apt-get install and still have this problem.

Comment: post the output of java -version

Comment: i dont know what you mean post the output of java

Comment: are you using the java standalone package or you installed minecraft via .deb?

Comment: by the way, he meant, post your terminal output after running the command "java -version" on your terminal so we could know what version of java are you using

Comment: I installed minecraft .deb and i use java 8 because I had 11 before and it wouldnt work either way.